# Rotate bodies around around a center point

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

I have a game world in which the player rotates around a point (like a planet). How can I rotate a body around a center point? I also want to somehow be able to use something like the actor classes interpolation for moving things, is that possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate via vector2 easly.

```
Vector2 vectorbody = new Vector2(50f, 50f);
Vector2 vectorcenter = new Vector2(100f,100f); 
Vector2 vectordis= vectorbody.cpy().sub(vectorcenter);//Displacement vector center to body
vectordis.setAngle( vectordis.angle() + rotatespeed );//Rotate speed can be negative that means it will rotates to other side.
vectordis.add(vectorcenter); //vectordis now became rotated vectorbody
vectorbody.set(vectordis);   //vectorbody updated
```

You can also use actor methods.

Just define new variable like *is_in_orbit* and if its true (in orbit) then rotate otherwise move with a actor classes interpolation methods.

By the way you also have a opinion to use physics since Newton's law of universal gravitation is also physics but it will be complicated and can cause unexpected results in case of more center points (planets as you said) appear.

Comment: I know I could use the actor class, but I was wanting to also use box2d as the collision. I am still confused on something though, how do I actually rotate the body? I see that you are using vectors to get an angle, how do I set the body to that angle?

Comment: actually i got the position. 
vectorbody.x and vectorbody.y is new coordinates of body. 
You can set position of body with  bodyDef.position.set(vectorbody.x,vectorbody.y);

Comment: i guess missunderstood you . i was talking about position when body rotate around center not rotation of body. You can research about body.setTransform(body.getPosition(), angle);

Comment: I setup setTransform on the body, but something very strange happens. Setting the angle in setTransform with a position of 0, 0 rotates around the center of the screen (Like I want it to). The strange part is that when I set the angle to 1, it jumps way more than 1 degree, more like 45 degrees. If I set it to 5 degrees, then it is already all the way almost 360 degrees.

Comment: Fixed it, i had to use degrees to radians.

Comment: yeah libgdxs angle() returns in degree

Comment: by the way can you accept answer since your problem solved.